# How can I define a convection term that includes an independent variable?

Tags: fipy

**My equations are as shown in the figure, and while the equations themselves aren't particularly complex, I'm having trouble figuring out how to define them in FiPy. I've tried some code, but I keep getting errors. How can I define the second term in the second equation and the second term in the third equation?**
[The PDE Equations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UsAp.png)

```
Error:
--> 250     assert len(id1) == len(id2) == len(vector)
    252     temp = sp.csr_matrix((vector, (id1, id2)), self.matrix.shape)
    254     self.matrix = self.matrix + temp

AssertionError:
```

```
    def CreatEquation(self):
        #h
        self.R = self.P * numerix.cos(self.slopeAngle) - self.i
        self.eq_h = TransientTerm(var=self.h) + ConvectionTerm(var=self.h, coeff=[self.u]) == self.R

        #u
        self.f = 8 * self.g * self.h * numerix.sin(self.slopeAngle) / (self.u**2)
        self.Sfx = (self.u / numerix.sqrt(8 * self.g / self.f))**2 / self.h
        self.eq_u = (TransientTerm(var=self.u) + ConvectionTerm(var=self.u, coeff=[self.u]) + 
                    ConvectionTerm(var=self.h, coeff=[self.g])) == (
                        self.g * (numerix.tan(self.slopeAngle) - self.Sfx) +
                        self.P * numerix.cos(self.slopeAngle) * self.Vm / self.h -
                        self.R * self.u / self.h
                    )
        
        #h & u
        self.eqns = self.eq_h & self.eq_u
```

When I set the coeff to 1, I don't encounter any errors, but that doesn't represent the equation correctly. How can I define the second term in the second equation and the second term in the third equation without causing errors?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

- `[self.u]` is not a vector field; it's a Python list with a scalar field in it. Instead, write `self.u * [[1]]`.
- [image: u(du/dx)] and [image: g(dh/dx)] aren't in canonical form for convection terms.

  - [image: u(du/dx) equivalence], so you could write `ConvectionTerm(coeff=u/2, var=u)`.
  - [image: g(dh/dx) equivalence], so you could write `ConvectionTerm(coeff=g, var=h) - ImplicitSourceTerm(coeff=g.grad, var=h)`.

Generally speaking, 1D equations are an excellent way to get really confused about how to represent things in FiPy (and in general, IMO). It's impossible to tell which derivatives are physically vector and physically scalar.

Comment: Thank you for the previous assistance. I've implemented the first two terms successfully `ConvectionTerm(var=self.h, coeff=self.u * [[1]]) `and `ConvectionTerm(var=self.u, coeff=(self.u/2) *[[1]])`, but for the third term, the code you provided keeps giving errors. I am using g for gravitational acceleration in `(self.g * self.h.arithmeticFaceValue).divergence`. Although my current code runs without errors, the solution does not converge. Could someone verify if my implementation is correct or provide additional guidance to resolve this issue?

Comment: `self.f = 8 * self.g * self.h * numerix.sin(self.slopeAngle) / (self.u**2)
        self.Sfx = (self.u / numerix.sqrt(8 * self.g / self.f))**2 / self.h
        self.equ = ( TransientTerm(var=self.u) + 
                    ConvectionTerm(var=self.u, coeff=(self.u/2) *[[1]])  + 
                    (self.g * self.h.arithmeticFaceValue).divergence ) == (
                    self.g * (numerix.tan(self.slopeAngle) - self.Sfx) +
                    self.P * numerix.cos(self.slopeAngle) * self.Vm / self.h -
                    self.R * self.u /self.h 
                    )`

Comment: `(self.g * self.h.arithmeticFaceValue).divergence` does not represent $g(\partial h/\partial x)$. It is also not implicit, which will hinder convergence. What errors did you get with the code I provided?

Comment: StackOverflow in general, and the comments in particular, are not well-suited to a back and forth conversation. Can we take this to https://github.com/usnistgov/fipy/discussions?

Comment: I will take this question to the link